# XSLT transformations grouping the nodes based on its value

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0

I am new to XSLT can any one help me with below transformations

This is my input XML:

```
<sent_items>
    <item>
        <RECEIPT_NUM>1</RECEIPT_NUM>
        <SHIPMENT_NUM>1</SHIPMENT_NUM>
        <ITEM_NUMBER>10</ITEM_NUMBER>
    </item>
    <item>
        <RECEIPT_NUM>2</RECEIPT_NUM>
        <SHIPMENT_NUM>2</SHIPMENT_NUM>
        <ITEM_NUMBER>100</ITEM_NUMBER>
    </item>
    <item>
        <RECEIPT_NUM>1</RECEIPT_NUM>
        <SHIPMENT_NUM>1</SHIPMENT_NUM>
        <ITEM_NUMBER>20</ITEM_NUMBER>
    </item>
    <item>
        <RECEIPT_NUM>2</RECEIPT_NUM>
        <SHIPMENT_NUM>2</SHIPMENT_NUM>
        <ITEM_NUMBER>30</ITEM_NUMBER>
    </item>
    <item>
        <RECEIPT_NUM>3</RECEIPT_NUM>
        <SHIPMENT_NUM>3</SHIPMENT_NUM>
        <ITEM_NUMBER>40</ITEM_NUMBER>
    </item>
</sent_items>
```

This is my output XML: i.e if we have same values in `RECEIPT_NUM` and `SHIPMENT_NUM` then add multiple `ITEM_NUMBER` nodes in the same `item` node.

```
<recived_items>
    <item>
        <RECEIPT_NUM>1</RECEIPT_NUM>
        <SHIPMENT_NUM>1</SHIPMENT_NUM>
        <ITEM_NUMBER>10</ITEM_NUMBER>
        <ITEM_NUMBER>20</ITEM_NUMBER>
    </item>
    <item>
        <RECEIPT_NUM>2</RECEIPT_NUM>
        <SHIPMENT_NUM>2</SHIPMENT_NUM>
        <ITEM_NUMBER>100</ITEM_NUMBER>
        <ITEM_NUMBER>30</ITEM_NUMBER>
    </item>
    <item>
        <RECEIPT_NUM>3</RECEIPT_NUM>
        <SHIPMENT_NUM>3</SHIPMENT_NUM>
        <ITEM_NUMBER>40</ITEM_NUMBER>
    </item>
</recived_items>
```

I have used for-each as shown in below two example but both of them did not give expected output.
1)XSLT:

```
<recived_items>
    <xsl:for-each select="/sent_items/item">
    <item>
        <RECEIPT_NUM><xsl:value-of select="RECEIPT_NUM"/></RECEIPT_NUM>
        <SHIPMENT_NUM><xsl:value-of select="SHIPMENT_NUM"/></SHIPMENT_NUM>
        <ITEM_NUMBER><xsl:value-of select="ITEM_NUMBER"/></ITEM_NUMBER>
    </item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</recived_items>
```

2)XSLT:

```
<recived_items>

    <item>
        <RECEIPT_NUM><xsl:value-of select="RECEIPT_NUM"/></RECEIPT_NUM>
        <SHIPMENT_NUM><xsl:value-of select="SHIPMENT_NUM"/></SHIPMENT_NUM>
        <xsl:for-each select="/sent_items/item">
        <ITEM_NUMBER><xsl:value-of select="ITEM_NUMBER"/></ITEM_NUMBER>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </item>
</recived_items>
```

please help me with writing the XSLT which will give the expected output XML.

Comment: This is a grouping problem, and the solution in XSLT 1.0 is to use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is a grouping problem, solved in XSLT 1.0 using Muenchian grouping

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="group" match="item" use="concat(RECEIPT_NUM, '|', SHIPMENT_NUM)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(RECEIPT_NUM, '|', SHIPMENT_NUM))[1])]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="* | key('group', concat(RECEIPT_NUM, '|', SHIPMENT_NUM))[position() > 1]/ITEM_NUMBER"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('group', concat(RECEIPT_NUM, '|', SHIPMENT_NUM))[1]))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```